# Question about biggest known CouchDB (or other) cluster

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I am evaluating CouchDB. My evaluation covers many aspects, and one of these aspects is the maximum number of nodes that can be used.

So, I want to know how many nodes has the biggest (number of nodes) real-world CouchDB application.

Is this kind of questions appropriate for Programmers?

Answer (score 4):

Have you run into scaling issues with CouchDB? Then by all means ask about them, and we'll be glad to help.

But "how many nodes has the biggest application" doesn't really work, you are not looking for a solution to an actual practical problem. Your question is vague (define biggest: by data volume, traffic, both?), time dependent (the biggest application today won't be the biggest tomorrow) and its answers won't really answer your question. Assuming application foo has a bazillion node, why is a bazillion the maximum number of supported nodes?

Programmers can be extremely helpful when you've already started designing or even building your project, but not so much before.

Comment: I should have been more precise, by biggest I meant number of nodes. For instance, I know some technology that can't scale over 4 nodes. I edited my question, thanks!

Comment: @nicolas Still that's not the main issue of the question: you are asking for a list of apps by number of nodes and lists dont work with the Q&A philosophy and format of the site.